# ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1: Fire button events without using Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, onclick

I have a simple HTML control with a textbox displaying a numeric value and an increment and decrement button

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="button" value="-" />
        <input asp-for="@pizza.Quantity" />
        <input type="button" value=" + " />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a href="#">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Behind the scenes, there is an equally simple ViewModel:

```
public class CartViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

When clicking one of the buttons, the value should be either incremented or decremented. How would I best go about wiring events to said buttons without using Javascript? Is it possible to do so without having to use form elements?

Comment: If you just create a link to the action method, that would make GET request without a form element or Javascript. See e.g. `Html.ActionLink`, `Url.Action`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTML5 or many "bootstrap" controls/plugins

in this example you have min/max as well

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number

Quantity (between 1 and 5):

**Note:** type="number" is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

Bootstrap millions of plugins like
https://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin/

Answer (score -1):

A html control event could not be executed without the help of javascript. To achieve events to be fired without JavaScript wireup then the only possible way to use the server side button(asp:button)

Comment: Hi Navan there is no javascript here HTML 5  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number